# Bitwise operator in java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, operators

When I wrote

```java
int x = 11<<12+12>>11;
```

and print x complier shows 45056 which makes sense as it is like `11<<24>>11` then solving first from left to right it is `11 * 2^24 / 2^11`.

Similarly for

```java
int x = 1<<12+1>>12;
```

it shows 2^23. But when I wrote

```java
int x = 1<<22+22>>1;
```

it is showing 2048 which is 2^11 rather than 2^41. Please correct me where I am wrong.

Comment: I don't get the same values you are getting. With the first example, I get `90112`, then for the second I get `2`. With the third example I get `2048`.

Comment: How many bits does an int have? 32 - and how do you think you can shift 44 bits to the left in a 32 bit value? In fact, Java only looks at the lower 5 bits, so it shifts 22 bits to the left, and then one to the right.

Answer (score 0):

All the following are equal

```
int x = 1<<22+22>> 1;
int x = (1<<(22+22))>>1
int x = 1<<44>>1
int x = 1<<12>>1
int x = 4096 >> 1
int x = 2048
```

When you shift an int by `N` you are shifting by the low order `5` bits of `N`.
When you shift a long by `N` you are shifting by the low order `6` bits of `N`

As explained in the [Java Language Specification - bitwise operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)

Section 15.19

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, then only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is long, then only the six lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x3f (0b111111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 63, inclusive.